# R: lme4's nlmer error variable not found

Tags: r, lme4

The data in the following example are from [here](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~lang/Stat527a/aids.dat2)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
dat <- read.table("aids.dat2",head=T) %>%
  filter(day <= 90) %>%
  mutate(log10copy = log10(lgcopy)) %>%
  na.omit()

> head(dat)
  patid day    cd4   lgcopy    cd8 log10copy
2 11542   2 159.84 4.361728 619.38 0.6396586
3 11542   7 210.60 3.531479 666.90 0.5479566
4 11542  16 204.12 2.977724 635.04 0.4738844
5 11542  29 172.48 2.643453 407.68 0.4221716
6 11542  57 270.94 2.113943 755.78 0.3250933
8 11960   2 324.72 3.380211 856.08 0.5289438
```

Running the following code gives me the error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'log10copy' not found`, but `log10copy` is clearly one of the columns in my data set?

```
lme4.fit <- lme4::nlmer(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1) + 
                          (1|p1) + (1|b1) + (1|p2) + (1|b2), data = dat)
```

I want to fit a model with 4 fixed effects on `p1`, `b1`, `p2`, `b2` and 4 random effects on the same set of parameters.

Comment: The formula for `nlmer` should be a 3-part formula of the form `resp ~ Nonlin ~ fixed + random`. Also what are p1, p2, b1, b2? They are not in your example data.

Comment: @neilfws p1, p2, b1 and b2 are my parameters

Comment: @neilfws I updated my post with some new code (according to the syntax you suggested), but now I'm running into a different error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here...

1) The starting values must be a named vector
2) the `data` argument in nlmer should receive `dat` as value and not `aids.dat` as in your example

```
start <- c(p1 = 10, b1 = 0.5, p2 = 6, b2 = 0.005)
lme4.fit <- lme4::nlmer(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1) ~ 
                            (p1|patid) + (b1|patid) + (p2|patid) + (b2|patid), data = dat,
                        start = start)
```

This will now trigger the following error :

```
Erreur : is.matrix(gr <- attr(val, "gradient")) is not TRUE
```

As explained in the documentation :

> Currently, the Nonlin(..) formula part must not only return a numeric
>   vector, but also must have a "gradient" attribute, a matrix. The
>   functions SSbiexp, SSlogis, etc, see selfStart, provide this (and
>   more). Alternatively, you can use deriv() to automatically produce
>   such functions or expressions.

You can then adapt the example provided by the documentation  :

```
## a. Define formula
nform <- ~ exp(p1-b1*input) + exp(p2-b2*input + 1)
## b. Use deriv() to construct function:
nfun <- deriv(nform, namevec=c("p1", "b1", "p2", "b2"),
              function.arg=c("input","p1", "b1", "p2", "b2"))
lme4.fit <- lme4::nlmer(log10copy ~ nfun(day, p1, b1, p2, b2) ~ 
                            (p1|patid) + (b1|patid) + (p2|patid) + (b2|patid), data = dat,
                        start = start)
```

You will then have the following error

```
Error in fn(nM$xeval()) : prss failed to converge in 300 iterations
```

This might mean that your model is too complex for your data...
Or maybe I did a mistake in the specification as I' don't know nlmer very well (I just tried to apply the documentation...) nor do I know your model/question.

When you change the optimizer, the convergence problems seem to be gone...
See [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#troubleshooting) for recommendations about "troubleshooting" (including convergence problems) with `lme4`

```
lme4.fit <- lme4::nlmer(log10copy ~ nfun(day, p1, b1, p2, b2) ~ 
                            (p1|patid) + (b1|patid) + 
                            (p2|patid) + (b2|patid), 
                        data = dat,
                        start = start, 
                        nlmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```